# Need Help: Matlab Function Plotting

Tags: matlab

Why won't my matlab function plot? Whenever I enter in a variable I no lines come up in my matlab figure.

Here's the code:

---

```
%we have decided to emulate an auditory sensor

function GroupSensorFun1(N) %user chooses # of variables

    %creating sensor data for time and decibles

    timeVec = 1:1:N; %vector emulates N seconds

    soundVec = 1000/rand(N,1) %randomly generates N readings

    hold on

    for i = 1:N %loop N times to plot all data

        %plot data on to scatter graph one varible at a time.

        %scatter(timeVec(i),soundVec(i))

        plot(timeVec(i),soundVec(i))

    end

    % Create xlabel

    xlabel({'Time in Seconds'});

    % Create ylabel

    ylabel({'Decibles scaled'});

    % Create title

    title({'Auditory Sensor Data in ', num2str(N) ' Seconds'});

    hold off
```

Comment: Do you really need the for loop? I mean couldn't you simply use `plot(timeVec,soundVec)`?

Comment: Please don't double-space code.  It's hard to read.

Comment: Without a set of reproducible data, how can we tell whether you're trying to plot NaNs or Infs?

Comment: Whilst I do consider myself flattered by the "thank you", since I am part of "everyone", this is now no longer a question. This will likely get closed or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
%we have decided to emulate an auditory sensor

function GroupSensorFun1(N) %user chooses # of variables

    %creating sensor data for time and decibles

    timeVec = 1:1:N; %vector emulates N seconds

    soundVec = 1000/rand(N,1) %randomly generates N readings

    %scatter(timeVec,soundVec)

    plot(timeVec,soundVec,'o')

    % Create xlabel

    xlabel('Time in Seconds');

    % Create ylabel

    ylabel('Decibles scaled');

    % Create title

    title(['Auditory Sensor Data in '  num2str(N) ' Seconds']);
```

You don't need a for to make a scatter plot, just plot without lines and a symbols ('o' in this case)